# How to import historical open price in Google Sheets with GOOGLEFINANCE?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, import, google-finance

For some reason, I can't get the google finance function to work with any open-price lookups I do.

For example:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL","priceopen", DATE(2019,4,12))
```

comes back as `#N/A` with message:

> {Error|Function `GOOGLEFINANCE` parameter 2 value is invalid for the symbol specified.}

I change the dates and tickers, but it never works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually kind of makes sense. If the 2nd parameter of **`GOOGLEFINANCE`** is **`"priceopen"`** it tries to fetch the open price but by adding a historical date to it **`DATE(2019,4,12)`** the 2nd parameter is confused because on that date there is no open price. On that date is only closed price at this moment. In other words: "the historical open price" is called **"open"**.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "priceopen")
```

[image: 0]

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "open", DATE(2019,4,12))
```

[image: 0]

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("AAPL", "open", DATE(2019,4,12)), 2,  2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Appreciate the help, but what you've got there is the close price for april 12th, how would you get the open price for april 12th?

Comment: @dlight answer updated